# How to load filtered data in html table using jquery & .net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I've this structure of c# class

```
public class test : PageModel
{
public JArray Transactions { get; set; }
public void  OnGet(int filterid)
{
  Transactions = GetTableValue(filterid);
}
}
```

actually my table works fine when it's load first time on page load.but when I tried to pass some filter values to onget method their I'm getting require response Transactions but it's not reflecting in table

this is the sample syntax i'm using.. please let me if you've any solutions

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
function SubmitFilter()
{
    var transactionNumb = $("#transactionNumber").val();   
    $.get("https://localhost:7197/Transactions?filterid="+transactionNumb , response=> {
     
    }); 
}
<table id="tblTransactions" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>  
        <td scope="col">Type</td>
        <td scope="col">Status</td>
        
    </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
        </tbody>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (dynamic transaction in @Model.Transactions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@transaction.type</td>
            <td>@transaction.status</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table> 
}
```

Comment: Here you have two options are there one is a partial view implementation and the second is the jquery database implementation both need to use with ajax.

Comment: What are the details of `GetTableValue`? what does it return?

Comment: GetTableValue returns Jarray value

Comment: I think you may follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0). If you have to use jquery ajax to update the view, I'm afraid you have to add much code to modify the dom elements